# I need to prove that there is one homomorphism $\varphi : Dn \to Sn$ such that

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, permutations, dihedral-groups

I need to prove that there is one homomorphism $\varphi : Dn \to Sn$ such that

$\varphi$($\tau$) =

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & . & .& . & n \\
        2 & 3 & . & .& . & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$\varphi$($\sigma$) =

$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 2 & 3 & .& n-1 & n \\
        1 & n & n-1 & .& 3 & 2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

I understand that each number is a vertex and that tau means
a turn one vertex to the right taking each number to the next
and sigma is a mirror. beside that I don't really understand what is the question.
any help will be aprriciated

Comment: How is $D_n$ defined?

Comment: i assume that Dn is the dihedral group but they don't say anything about it.

Comment: You need to show that those permutations satisfy the same relations $\tau$ and $\sigma$ satisfy. $\tau^n=1$, $\sigma^2=1$, $\sigma\tau=\tau^{-1}\sigma$.

Comment: tnx. but how does it prove that it is homomorphism and that there is only one?

Comment: ok i understand the homomorphism but what about the "one"?

Comment: A homomorphism is completely determined by its value on the generators.  You can prove this by writing an arbitrary element as a word in the generators.

Comment: I still dont get how to show there is no other homomorphism

Comment: Suppose you had another homomorphism $\psi : D_n \to S_n$ such that $\psi(\tau) = \varphi(\tau)$ and $\psi(\sigma) = \varphi(\sigma)$.  Show that $\psi = \varphi$ by writing an arbitrary element of $D_n$ as a word in $\sigma$ and $\tau$, as I suggested above.